# Correct syntax for "if" expression in simpleeval (Simple Eval)

Tags: python

I try to use [simpleeval](https://github.com/danthedeckie/simpleeval) library to evaluate some expressions from user text input. Here is code example.

```
!pip install simpleeval

from simpleeval import EvalWithCompoundTypes

COMPOUND_TYPES_NAMES = {
    'null': None,
    "true": True,
    "false": False
}
block = "set_value('user_city', get_slot('city_entity'), 'unknown') if get_slot('city_entity')"

def get_slot(slot: str) -> str:
    return None

def set_value(var_name: str, var_value: str, context: str):
    print(var_name, var_value)

EvalWithCompoundTypes(
    functions={
        "get_slot": lambda slot: get_slot(slot),
        'set_value': lambda var_name, var_value, context: set_value(var_name, var_value, context)
    },
    names=COMPOUND_TYPES_NAMES).eval(block)
```

In the example above when evaluating the expression defined in the string variable the following mistake occurred:

```
set_value('user_city', get_slot('city_entity'), 'unknown') if get_slot('city_entity')
                                                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is the correct syntax for the expression above?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that library, but that's not legal Python if that's the intent. A conditional expression requires an `else`.

Comment: Have you tried parsing this with the underlying, standard-Python-library `ast` module? SimpleEval uses ast under the hood; if ast won't accept it, SimpleEval certainly won't. (And it _doesn't_ -- see this tested at https://ideone.com/UA5Ml7; maybe you're thinking of Ruby syntax?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem isn't specific to SimpleEval. `expression if condition` isn't valid syntax in general, and you can validate this using the standard-library function `ast.parse()` (which is what SimpleEval is doing under the hood).

Consider `condition and expression`, or `expression if condition else None`.

Comment: After changing my block expression to "set_value('user_city', get_slot('city_entity'), 'unknown') if get_slot('city_entity') else None" works like a charm!